EAS build fail after install react-native-smartlook-analytics expo sdk 50
I got error while try to build eas after install smartlook packaage
error occuruing on after Linking step
ld: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lc++'
⚠️  ld: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftXPC': library 'swiftXPC' not found
⚠️  ld: Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'CoreAudioTypes': framework 'CoreAudioTypes' not found
❌  ld: Undefined symbols:
❌  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
EAS build IOS after install react-native-smartlook-analytics

When I use eas build --platform ios --local --non-interactive it works fine but the issue on build global, not local
